# Finding the shape corresponding to a set of points

Tags: algorithm, graph, point

I'm working on a small problem right now.

I'm reading in from a file a set of points, and I am asked to find the area inside of them (there is more to the problem, but I'm not worried about that right now).  I am given the number of points, and the problem I have is that my area function does not work if the points are not a edge traversal.

For example:  If the set of points is `[(0,0) , (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]`, it will correctly calculate the area as `1`.  However, if the set of points is given as `[(0,0) , (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]`, it will return `0` as the area.

How can I take the list of points, and have it find a traversal (either clockwise or counterclockwise, it doesn't matter)?  I'm not familiar with any fast algorithms to do so.

Note:  This is not a convex-hull problem.  The shape does not necessarily have to be convex.  For example, the set of points `[(0,0), (0,2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 0)]` is a valid shape.

Comment: If the order matters, you shouldn't be talking about sets.  And if the same set of points (as in your example) defines two distinct traversals, what do you mean by "find a traversal"?

Comment: Think about the set of points [(0,0), (0,2), (1, 1.5), (2, 2), (2, 0)]. (I moved the middle point up a bit.) This is not enough information to get an unambiguous shape. It's going to be a square with a triangle cut out from it, but there's no way to know if the cutout is in the top, bottom, or sides, and because I moved the point from 1 to 1.5, these shapes have different areas. Figure out what side has the cutout, and you'll be in much better shape.